# Why is the "matches" option not working for cordova-plugin-speechrecognition?

Tags: android, cordova, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech-recognition-api

**Problem**: using the "[Cordova Plugin for Speech Recognition](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition)" in an Android app, the `startListening()` function almost always returns *5 matches*, despite setting `matches: 1`.

- `matches` [is defined as](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/401/how-to-use-the-speech-recognition-api-in-cordova): {Number} number of return matches (default `5`)

For example:

- speaking: "What's up"
- returns: "what's up,whatsup,watsup,wat's up,what sup"

**Question**: how can I restrict the output to return just a single value/best match?

Sample code to illustrate how I have set the `matches` option:

```
function startRecognition(inputFieldId){
    window.plugins.speechRecognition.startListening(function(result){
        // Show the result in the corresponding input field     
        document.getElementById(inputFieldId).setAttribute("value", result);
    }, function(err)    {
        console.error(err);
    }, {
        language: "en-US", matches: 1, prompt: "", showPopup: false
    });
};
```

**Note**: modifying the other options, like `prompt` works fine, but modifying `matches` does nothing.